# Color-Thief Node plugin error: "Image given has not completed loading"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, color-thief

Working in Node/Express, I was trying to get the npm package [color-thief](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/) to grab the dominant color from an image, and it failed because "image given has not completed loading".

The image was, again, local, so it *shouldn't* have had this particular problem. And besides that, `color-thief` returns a promise, and I was using async/await, so it should have waited however long it took for the image *to* load instead of throwing an error.

Below is my SSCCE code:

```
const ColorThief = require('color-thief');

let colorThief = new ColorThief();

async function getDominantColor() {
    const img = 'public/img/seed/big-waves-2193828__340.webp';
    const dominantColor = await colorThief.getColor(img);
    console.log(dominantColor);
}

getDominantColor();
```

Comment: is path correct? try starting with `./` i.e.: `const img = './public/img/seed/big-waves-2193828__340.webp';`

Comment: It turns out the issue is that the package (apparently) doesn't support `.webp` files. Documented in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the plugin apparently does not support `.webp` files.

It works fine with `.jpg` and `.png`, though the [Documentation](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/) (which isn't easy to get to) doesn't explicitly state what file types it does/does not support.

I've submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/issues/183) on Github to either add support for webp or update the documentation with an explicit list of supported filetypes, but the author states at the very bottom of his [blog](https://lokeshdhakar.com/color-thief/) regarding the project:

> "In the short term I'm not planning on doing any more work on the script."

Just figured I would try to save someone else using this in the future some headache and time

Answer (score 1):

As per R Greenstreet answer above, Color-Thief does not support other formats than `.jpg` or `.png`.
So to workaround this, you need to convert image on the fly.

The fastest and most convenient way I could find is just to use node `sharp` module. And the code itself is just a few lines...

```
const sharp = require('sharp');

let image = await sharp(imageData);
let imageData = await image.metadata();

if (imageData.format === 'webp') {
    image = await image.toFormat('png').toBuffer();
} else {
    image = await image.toBuffer();
}
```

I know, this is not the optimal solution, but if you want a stable fix, this should be fine.